# Trying to understand Caliburn Micro EventAggregator

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, caliburn.micro, eventaggregator

I understood how does EventAggregator work in Caliburn Micro but i don't understand this:

Let's take this as an example:

ViewModel A

```
private IEventAggregator _eventAggregator;
public ViewModelA(IEventAggregator eventAggregator)
{
   _eventAggregator = eventAggregator
   _eventAggregator.PublishOnUIThread("Hello");
}
```

ViewModel B

```
private IEventAggregator _eventAggregator;
public ViewModelA(IEventAggregator eventAggregator)
{
   _eventAggregator = eventAggregator
   _eventAggregator.Subscribe(this)
}
public void Handle(string message)
{ 
   MessageBox.Show(message + " From ViewModel B")
}
```

ViewModel C

```
private IEventAggregator _eventAggregator;
public ViewModelA(IEventAggregator eventAggregator)
{
   _eventAggregator = eventAggregator
   _eventAggregator.Subscribe(this)
}
public void Handle(string message)
{ 
   MessageBox.Show(message + " From ViewModel C")
}
```

So how can i select which viewmodel handle to use when i publish events?

Comment: You can create view model specific message types and have the interested parties listen/handle those types of messages.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> So how can i select which viewmodel handle to use when i publish events?

Several view models may subscribe to the same message. This is how event aggregation works. The publisher publishes a single message without any knowledge of the number of receivers.

If you want a particular view model to be able to subscribe to an event, it should implement the `IHandle<T>` intertface and call the `Subscribe` method on the event aggregator:

```
public class ViewModelA : IHandle<string>
{
    private readonly IEventAggregator _eventAggregator;

    public ViewModelA(IEventAggregator eventAggregator)
    {
        _eventAggregator = eventAggregator;
        _eventAggregator.Subscribe(this);
    }

    public void Handle(string message)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(message);
    }
}
```

All view models that does this will receive the message.

Answer (score 0):

I managed to send messages to particular viewmodels via Message class:

```
public class Message<TTarget, TValue>
{
    public TValue Value { get; set; }

    public Message(TValue value)
    {
        Value = value;
    }
}
```

Then add to a class

```
IHandle<Message<ViewModel, string>>
```

Usage:

```
_eventAggregator.PublishOnUIThread(new Message<ViewModel, string>("Hello from ViewModel"));
```